# How to make dropdownlist of currency codes using django model

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make dropdownlist of all countries iso-4217 currencycodes like below,

```
  AFN-Afghani
  EUR-Euro
  USD-Dollar
    ...
```

I have tried lot I don't get what I want. I just want to make it  like CountryField() from django-countries.I have tried django-internation there i have got confused with how to implement that. If there is any possible to implement this one do reply.. Any help Appreciable..

Comment: what you have tried so far ? show us some code.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/django-international/#id3   Please, I have tried this one I have got error like "RuntimeError: Model class international.models.Country doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS".

Comment: @VijiLakshmi: the error explains what to do: you should add the app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py`, so in this case `'international'`.

Comment: I have tried pycountry there also I dont get dropdownlist which gives "TypeError('Only one criteria may be given')".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have done this. Now, I have got  error django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "currency" of relation "configuration_currency" does not exist.

Comment: @VijiLakshmi: now you need to `migrate` the database such that it construct the correct tables.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I did but I have got migrations no apply. I also tried with delete migrations and done it again I got same as no apply migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got solution for this. after installing django internation by **pip install django-international** then,
add 'international' in settings.py.
just do in our model like below,

```
import international.models 
choices = international.models.currencies

class Currency(models.Model):
      currency_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=choices)
```